mistake in using id in react html tag
How to remove this error?
I have put id on div that on clicking the button would go to this place in the page. but id stands out as an below error.
error - Type ‘{ children: (’‘’ | Element | undefined)[]; id: string; className: string; }’ can not be assigned to the type “DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>”.ts(2322).
The ‘id’ property does not exist in the ‘DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>’ type.ts(2322).

while everything is running locally, everything works, although it is highlighted in red. when building, an error with this id comes out. I don't understand how to fix it. app is built in react typescript application
I haven't found anything that would help.

need more code example about how you assign the ID

id, just a string.

{header}
        {headerImage && (
          
        )}